# QC 35's having connection issues

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I saw that there were some updates to the Bluez bluetooth manager a while ago, and now my Bose QC 35 headphones are acting funky.

1. I keep seeing alerts that say "Authorization Request for Base QuietComfort 35, Service: Phonebook access".  No matter how many times I click "accept" or "always accept" the messages keep coming back.
2. When I turn the headphones off and on, I'll get a constant message in my ears about "Connecting to ", and that message pops up with "Service: Advanced Audio"
3. Eventually, I will go into the device manager and hit "Disconnect" (although the headphones are still trying to connect). **Then** if I use right-click on the device and hit "connect", the headphones tell me they are connected.
4. Sometimes at this point, the headphones work.  But sometimes I have to go into the "Sound" configuration, right click on the device under "Hardware" and change the profile from "A2DP Sink" to "HFP", and then back, and then I get sound.)

Heres /var/log/syslog from when I turn the Headphones on

```
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event27)
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (**) Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP)'
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event27 13:91 fd 113 paused 0
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (**) Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP): always reports core events
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event27"
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) event27 - Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) event27 - Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) event27 - Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP): device removed
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input43/event27"
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 24)
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) event27 - Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar 15 13:07:56 chi /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2566]: (II) event27 - Bose QuietComfort 35 (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Mar 15 13:07:58 chi bluetoothd[1144]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_2C_41_A1_09_32_EF/sep1/fd6: fd(39) ready
```

Keyboard?  Wait, what?

**UPDATE:** still no solution -- now I'm getting pop-ups saying "Authorization Request for Bose QuietComfort 35, Service: Remote Control".  I keep clicking "Always Accept", but the pop-ups just keep coming!

Comment: Yes, keyboard. It has function keys that send a signal indistinguishable from the one sent by typical multimedia keys in a regular keyboard. https://mobilityarena.com/bluetooth-profiles-protocols-hsp-a2dp-avrcp-hfp/

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution

1. Open the "Bluetooth Devices" manager
2. Right-click the headphones
3. One of the options will be "trust".  (3rd from bottom).  Choose that.

And now all those other messages have gone away, and the headphones "just work".